# How to convert from String[] to JTextField[]

Tags: java, string, jtextfield

I am trying to make a JTextField array based on the word length that is input from a file. I can't seem to find a way to convert from String[] to JTextField[].

```
//Splits the word chosen from word list into an array
JTextField[] wordAmount = new JTextField[word.length()];//Creates a JtextField for each letter
String[] items = word.split("");

String temp;
for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j ++) {
    temp = items[j];
    wordAmount[j].setText(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize each JTextField in the JTextField array before you call a method from it so before you call setText() method add this statement

```
wordAmount[j] = new JTextField();
```

so change your for loop to this

```
for (int j = 1; j < items.length; j++) {
            temp = items[j];
            wordAmount[j] = new JTextField();
            wordAmount[j].setText(temp);

}
```